# AWS sentinel 2 duplicate entry difference

Tags: sentinel-2, amazon-web-services

can anybody  explain what main difference between two almost identical directories:

1. http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/22/K/EC/2017/10/10/0/
2. http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/22/K/EC/2017/10/10/1/

These directories almost identical, but one contains preview and another does not.

Comment: This looks like an ingestion error to me. Metadata is identical apart from the ingestion timestamp. The ingestion is performed by Sinergise. I [sent them a link to this question](https://twitter.com/Fernerkundung/status/918843736091713537) - let's see what their response is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was indeed an ingestion error, caused by Sentinel-2B products appearing on both pre-operations hub and the open data hub. The directories indeed contain identical products. We have fixed the error and removed the duplicate tile from the bucket.

The list of removed items is available at http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/deleted-tiles.txt

Thanks for spotting this and letting us know.

EDIT: Added link to the list of deleted items.

Comment: would you also update productInfo.json? it contains incorrect url
http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/products/2017/10/9/S2B_MSIL1C_20171009T053659_N0205_R062_T43MBU_20171009T053701/productInfo.json http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/43/M/BU/2017/10/9/0/productInfo.json

Comment: @dr_times Thanks, we've updated productInfo.json as well